# My Light is not shining on the lit side of my imported object

Tags: lighting

For some reason my imported object is absorbing all the light, it does have some reflected light but none on the side it is lit from. I've tried increasing the light source but it doesn't help.

As you can see the object is sat on a plane and the plane is acting correctly to the light.

[image: Unlit object on a plane]
[image: Light settings]

Comment: maybe a normal problem? could you share your file (with the images packed if there are some): https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Hi Sorry I can't send the file because it comes from our R and D team and the object has a lot of internal parts that aren't meant to be public, I can send you any screen grab you want though?

Comment: have you flipped the normals? also make sure that in your Properties panel > Object Data > Geometry > Clear Custom Split Normals Data

Comment: Hi @moonboots,  Sorry it took me so long to come back to you I had to move to a different project. The "Clear Custom Split Normals Data" worked! I have no idea what that is but it worked all the same so thank you.

Comment: ok you're welcome  ;)

Answer (score 1):

Some imported objects have normal problems and display black artefacts, so in  *Properties* panel > *Object Data > Geometry* > click on *Clear Custom Split Normals Data*.